# How To Do A Webkit Slide Cover Page Transition

Tags: android, css, webkit, sencha-touch

In working with Android, CSS, and jQuery, I'm trying to grasp how to do a slide cover webkit transition like is used in [Sencha Touch](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/). Basically I have home.html and options.html. I click a button on home.html and it needs to do a slide cover webkit transition from left-to-right, switching from home.html to options.html.

What's the technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its really simple basically - you just make your covers positioned absolutely, the home cover with `left:0;` and the options cover with `left:100%;` then, if you want to show options, you first load it with an ajax request, as soon as the request finishes, you use a webkit-transform / transition to position the home cover with `left:-100%` and the options cover with `left:0%;`.

very good code examples can be seen in jqtouch http://www.jqtouch.com/ (the author of jqtouch now works for sencha). further information can also be found in this article http://blazingcloud.net/2010/08/11/jqtouch-slide-transition-fix-for-android-2-0/

Comment: So I need to use jQuery and AJAX, right, to load a copy of the other page into the given page, and slide it into place with a webkit-transform. So, essentially, one doesn't leave index.html -- they just see options.html inside index.html, like sliding cards. Right?

Comment: yes, thats in my opinion the cleanest solution for a smooth animation. maybe even save you some time and use jqtouch directly, as this function is easily available there ...

Comment: I finally got this working with your help. The -100%, 0px, and 100% technique did the trick with -webkit-transition on the margin-left property.